# holomorphic functions, such that $|f|$ depends only on $Re \ z$ and $arg \ f$ depends only on $Im \ z$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to describe all holomorphic functions, such that $|f|$ depends only on $\text{Re}\, z$ and $\text{arg}\, f$ depends only on $\text{Im}\, z$.

My thoughts:

Let $f=u+vi, z=x+iy$, then $0=d |f|^2/d y=vv_y+uu_y$ and $0= d\text{ arg}(f) / dx=d \tan^{-1}(v/u)/dx={uv_x-vu_x}/{u^2+v^2}$. So there is system of differential equations
$$
uv_x-vu_x=0, \
vv_y+uu_y=0.
$$
But due to Cauchy–Riemann equations $vv_y+uu_y=-(uv_x-vu_x)$ so I have only $1$ equation. I don't know what should I next.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $f(z) = \exp(g(z))$, then what can you say about the real and imaginary parts of $g$?

Comment: Let $g=u+iv$, $u$ depends only on $x$ and $v$ depends only on $y$, and by Cauchy–Riemann equations $u_x=v_y$, so $u=v+C$, $C \in \mathbb R$. $f=e^{v+C+iv}$, is it the answer?                            PS. Why does there exist $g$, $f=exp(g)$? I think we can find such $g$ only locally, because we don't have $ln$ in $\mathbb C$

Comment: No, $u_x = v_y$ (where left side is a function of $x$ and right side a function of $y$) implies $u_x = v_y = c$ for some constant $c$.  Assuming $f$ is not identically $0$, $f$ is never $0$ (think about why...) and $g$ exists as an antiderivative of $f'/f$ on any simply-connected domain.